# Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)

Tags: html, html-select

Can someone confirm that its **not** possible to change the height of a dropdown that is shown when you click on a select box.

The size attribute of the select makes it look like a list, the height attribute in the CSS doesnt do much good either.

Comment: The drop-down is an application-level control, not a client-level control. (sadly)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Confirmed.

The part that drops down is set to either:

1. The height needed to show all entries, or
2. The height needed to show `x` entries (with scrollbars to see remaining), where `x` is

   - 20 in Firefox & Chrome
   - 30 in IE 6, 7, 8
   - 16 for Opera 10
   - 14 for Opera 11
   - 22 for Safari 4
   - 18 for Safari 5
   - 11 in IE 5.0, 5.5
3. In IE/Edge, if there are no options, a stupidly high list of 11 blanks entries.

For (3) above you can see the results in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Ltzwa5/)

Comment: @scunliffe how to set (1) in chrome

Comment: If you set size="1" or nothing since it is the default then your select will be a drop down vs a static vertical in Page list.  However as noted the actual dropdown height is determined by the browser and as developers we have no control over the list height.

Comment: @scunliffe Hats-off for the counts provided :)

Answer (score 11):

**NO**. It's not possible to change height of a select dropdown because that property is browser specific.

However if you want that functionality, then there are many options. You can use bootstrap `dropdown-menu` and define it's `max-height` property. Something like this.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    var htmlText = text + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(htmlText);
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 146px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.caret {
   float: right;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#menu1 {
    width: 160px; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   
<div class="container" style="margin:10px">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that it's not the best practice for changing the height of the `select`, but there is a code that maybe helps you to change the height.

Using the `size` attribute of the `select` tag:

```html
<select onfocus='this.size=6;' onblur='this.size=6;' onfocusout='this.size=null;' onchange='this.size=6; this.blur();'>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
    <option>Option 6</option>
    <option>Option 7</option>
    <option>Option 8</option>
    <option>Option 9</option>
    <option>Option 10</option>
    <option>Option 11</option>
    <option>Option 12</option>
    <option>Option 13</option>
    <option>Option 14</option>
    <option>Option 15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

i have been working on a dropdown replacement jquery plugin to combat this problem. As of this post, it is almost indistinguishable from a native dropdown in terms of look and **functionality**.

here is a demo (also a link to downloads):
http://programmingdrunk.com/current-projects/dropdownReplacement/

here is the project page of the plugin:

<strike>http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dropdownreplacement</strike>

(update:)
the jquery plugin page seems to no longer work. I will probably not put my plugin on their new site when they get it working, so feel free to use the programmingdrunk.com link for demo/download

Comment: interesting idea - I certainly like the ability to "skin" the fake select list (I find many default from the "native" OS theme and thus look "odd"), and the ability to control the content in the list I find handy (since IE provides very little styling options for option elements)

Comment: The last link from this answer is dead !

Comment: yep, but the demo page is a better resource than the plugin site. it also has a download on it. ill update the answer though, thanks

Comment: This looks awesome :D I wonder if you have time to test it with some later version of jquery. Thank you

Comment: I do not, but if you do, feel free to report back :) - actually I know that it works with 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

Actually you kind of can! Don't hassle with javascript... I was just stuck on the same thing for a website I'm making and if you increase the 'font-size' attribute in CSS for the  tag then it automatically increases the height as well. Petty but it's something that bothers me a lot ha ha

Comment: I would assume the goal would be to show more choices in the dropdown box, not to simply take up more space, which is what this answer would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect solution but it sort of does work.

In the select tag, include the following attributes where 'n' is the number of dropdown rows that would be visible.

```
<select size="1" position="absolute" onclick="size=(size!=1)?n:1;" ...>
```

There are three problems with this solution.  1) There is a quick flash of all the elements shown during the first mouse click.  2) The position is set to 'absolute' 3) Even if there are less than 'n' items the dropdown box will still be for the size of 'n' items.

Comment: Good try but no luck, also tried replacing it with onFocus .

Answer (score 0):

The **Chi Row** answer is a good option for the problem, but I've found an error i the `onclick` arguments. Instead, would be:

```
<select size="1" position="absolute" onclick="size=(size!=1)?1:n;" ...>
```

(And mention you must replace the "*n*" with the number of lines you need)

Answer (score 0):

My approach is different: I calculate and set the `size` of the `select` to match the available space.

1. I start with a smaller `select` than the available space
   I determine the actual height of each `option` by increasing the `size` of the `select` and seeing how its `offsetHeight` changes; this value is browser dependent
2. I calculate how many more options can fit
3. I increase the `size` of the `select` to a value that will make it fit

```
    // Make the select fit in the div`
    // The looks of a select are set by the browser, not by the client
    // Therefore, they change from browser to browser, and even with various revs of a given browser
    // This cannot be done at init, because the height of each option changes later
    // Instead, it must be done later, after the select has rendered 
    if (!seriesSelect.fitted) { // If we haven't done it yet
        seriesSelect.fitted = true; // Flag it, so we don't do it again
        // Determine the actual height of each option in the select
        var maxHeight = seriesSelect.parentElement.parentElement.offsetHeight;
        var startHeight = seriesListBox.offsetHeight;
        seriesSelect.size = seriesSelect.size +1;
        var endHeight = seriesListBox.offsetHeight;
        var lineHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
        // Calculate how many more options can fit
        var extraHeight = maxHeight - endHeight;
        var extraItems = Math.floor(extraHeight / lineHeight);
        // Set the number of options to the max that will fit
        seriesSelect.size = seriesSelect.size + extraItems;
    }
```