# length of dropdown list

Tags: html

i have a drop down list in my form. it contains a lot of values. so when i click on it, it covers whole of the page, along with the scroll bar. is there a way to limit the length of the drop down list, say showing only 10 values at a time. any help is very much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [height of an html select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a way to limit the size of the dropdown. It is browser/OS dependent.

You can try creating your own dropdown using javascript. There should be a JQuery plugin available.

If you want to stick to  then you will have to live with the too tall dropdowns.