# Limiting the displayed height of a select drop-down

Tags: html, css, select

I have a `<select>` with a lot of `<option>`'s. Is there any way to limit the height of the displayed `<select>` when opened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Comment: @bemace, it may be a dupe, but I didn't find that initially myself (and I always check the way I typed the question). I personally think dupe questions that rephrase in a way that could help someone else find it (like me!) and yet lead to the original are okay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the size limit is controlled by the browser and not something you can alter.

See this answer: [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown/570651#570651)

Comment: Yeah, this was just pointed out to me in #jquery. Thanks for the quick answer, though! Will accept this in 6 minutes.