# GWT 2.5.1 - limiting the number of visible entries in a drop-down list (ValueListBox)

Tags: css, gwt, web, internet-explorer-11

I am using a ValueListBox to display a list of values for the user to select.
My issue with  the list is that with IE11 its behavior is rather terrible when clicking on the control:
1. the list is shown all over it (imho it should properly display not over but *under* the current selection, which is how it behaves using Google Chrome)
2. too many entries are shown (IE11 shows 30, Chrome shows 20). Probably related: [Limiting the displayed height of a select drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457232/limiting-the-displayed-height-of-a-select-drop-down)

Is this an entirely browser-dependant behavior there is nothing to do about ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure it can't be done with a standard HTML `<select>` item, which is how GWT renders a `ValueListBox`, but you could try something like Bootstrap select: http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#select

(scroll down to *Visible Items Before Scroll*)

[image: Select widget from GwtBootstrap3 wrapper for Bootstrap]