# vertical scroll bar in select/option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to add a vertical scroll bar in the select/option control in order to limit the height. Please take a look at the following URL, look at the select/option control in the vehicle make (select year first), I want to do something like this.

https://www.lowestrates.ca/autoquoteon

I did a search in stackoverflow.com and I found a lot of discussion(s) in this topic, but I dont find anybody having answers.

I prefer JavaScript or JQuery and nothing else.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4457241/4183498

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `size` attribute for the select tag to limit the number of options [w3c select](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-select-element.html#attr-select-size)

`<select size="3" >
  <options...../>
</select>`