# How can I increase the number of items displayed in an open <select> box in IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

Can any one help me out in increasing the number of items displayed in an IE6 `<select>` box?

It has 11 items by default, and I need to display 13 items in the list when the `<select>` box is triggered.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, since the `<select>` is an application-level control, not a client-level control, so can't be altered very much from scripting.  [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

You may have to make your own from Javascript.

Comment: Yep, jQuery probably have lots of alternatives to offer, some of them simple to use.