# limiting select box list length - adding scrollbars

Tags: html, css

When i use an html select box which has about 50 items, I get a very long list that fully appears. I would like to use scrollbars instead. how do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406998/html-selectbox-list-size-count/  check this link for your probs..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use CSS, specifically height and overflow:

**CSS**

```
.select{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="select"></select>
```

If you need anything more specific, ask!

Comment: Oh, actually, yes - I thought tomer was after a dropdown sleect box :O

Comment: I'm confused now... He wanted to limit the number of elements on the dropdown ?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do this in HTML.  See [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

There are other ways of achiving this though javascript or jQuery, with links on that page to some jQuery plugins which create a "fake" html select box that looks and behaves like one, but can have the height set.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set the number of visible items for a single value select box. There is a size attribute, but that will transform the dropdown into multiple selection list.