# HTML selectbox List size count

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to control the selectbox dropdown size? Actually a property called **SIZE** is already there. But my requirement is, when I click that select box, options are populating, in that list can I control the size..

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: Consider preparing a JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem that you're facing.

Comment: i dont hav any code.. my problem is,in a select box 100 options are available.when we are clicking that select box all the 100 options are showing at a time.but i dont want this.i want to contol those 100 optins into 5s,10s and so on.if we scroll the it moving again into next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<select name="select1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}" onchange="this.size=0;" onblur="this.size=0;" style="position: absolute">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
<option>e</option>
<option>f</option>
<option>g</option>
<option>h</option>
<option>i</option>
<option>j</option>
<option>k</option>
<option>l</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ASIK RAJA A: is this what you were looking for?

Comment: S Avinash !!! Similar to this!!!. ur code is working for mouse operation but not for keyboard and i have changed this to keyboard event

Comment: like as follows                                          <html>
<head>
<script>
function setsize(obj){
if(obj.options.length>5){obj.size=5;}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<select name="select1" onkeyup='setsize(this)' onmousedown="setsize(this)" onchange="this.size=0;" onblur="this.size=0;" style="position: absolute">
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
<option>e</option>
<option>f</option>
<option>g</option>
<option>h</option>
<option>i</option>
<option>j</option>
<option>k</option>
<option>l</option>
</select>
</body>
</html> ....

Comment: so you want to move down the list by key also. i think its possible in my code. only problem is that list dont appear on keypress

Answer (score 0):

using this you will be able to limit the size.

```
<select name="select" id="select" size="2" >
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
<option>c</option>
<option>d</option>
<option>e</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanxz Avinash!!! But this is showing 2 options at a time..i already execute this...initially select box should show only one option and whenever we click on that select box, the options should control by limit...

Comment: ok I think you may be able to do that by setting the scroll size to 5. I will try and reply soon\