# height of the dropdown box display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adjust the height of the list in dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600646/adjust-the-height-of-the-list-in-dropdown-box)

hi

how can I adjust the height of the list in the dropdown because I have too many values loaded in the drop down box. For example, it only show 10 entries, and with scrollbars to see remaining. does anyone know how to do that? you may more clear to see my attached picture.

---

[image: dipaly only 5 options]
 this is what I want. it only show 5 entries, and with scrollbars to see remaining.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question, [forty minutes before asking *this* question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600646/adjust-the-height-of-the-list-in-dropdown-box)?

Comment: at least this one is worded better I suppose.

Comment: OK, I am sorry. I will not do that next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can not actually control the size of the dropdown box if you are using HTML . There are some ways to fake it using divs and scroll bars, but that is different

This is not easy, and requires several nested CSS styles and some Javascript but the HTML is below. It basically operates like a SharePoint style dropdown box, with some over effects and on click opens the scrolling options.

[image]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spsItems">
    <tbody>
        <tr contextmenuid="options-aaa" class="people_display">
            <td class="spsContext">Current Option</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr contextmenuid="options-bbb" class="people_display">
            <td class="spsContext">Current Option</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr contextmenuid="options-bbb" class="people_display">
            <td class="spsContext">Current Option</td>
        </tr>                               
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="options-aaa" class="spsContextMenu" >
    <ul> 
        <li>Option Value</li> 
        <li>Option Value</li> 
            .....
        <li>Option Value</li> 
        <li>Option Value</li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your html and css, lets see what's going on

Comment: http://tianwang.web44.net/selectheight.html I uploaded it to he website instead posted on top ,please see it

Comment: sorry I just realized I wasn't using a select/option html items in my personal code. I just used a DIV and a hidden <ul><li></li></ul> achieves the same effect but more difficult to implement