# Chrome bug OR fault on <select> <options>

Tags: html, google-chrome

I client of me came up with a strange bug in Chrome, he has created a select with options that change when they select a France department. I tried many things, and i discovered that it also happens in a raw html file with only the select in it. I have figured out that when i remove the options between my comments the select act normal, if i let them stand youll see it appears like some kind of multi select box. All suggestions or solutions are welcome, cause i can't find out where its go wrong.

Here is the HTML

```
<select name="bezienswaardigheid" id="bezienswaardigheid">
<option value="0" d="d0" s="0" style="display: none;">Geen voorkeur</option>
<option value="1" s="s6" d="d16" style="display: inline;">Baai van de Somme (natuurreservaat)</option>
<option value="2" s="s6" d="d9" style="display: none;">Boulogne sur Mer (levendige vissersstad)</option>
<option value="3" s="s1" d="d2" style="display: none;">Côte de Granit Rose (rode rotskust)</option>
<option value="14" s="s6" d="d9" style="display: none;">Cap Griz Nez (krijtrotsen)</option>
<option value="34" s="s1" d="d8" style="display: none;">Carnac (prehistorische monumenten)</option>
<option value="12" s="s4" d="d3" style="display: none;">D-Day invasiestranden</option>
<option value="4" s="s4" d="d3" style="display: none;">Deauville (mondaine badplaats)</option>
<!-- BUG OR FAULT STARTS HERE -->
<option value="5" s="s4" d="d10" style="display: none;">Dieppe (historische badplaats)</option>
<option value="6" s="s1" d="d6" style="display: none;">Dinard (oude vissersplaats)</option>
<option value="15" s="s4" d="d10" style="display: none;">Etretat (krijtrotsen)</option>
<option value="8" s="s4" d="d10" style="display: none;">Fécamp(historische badplaats)</option>
<option value="9" s="s4" d="d3" style="display: none;">Honfleur (artistiek stadje)</option>
<option value="11" s="s2" d="d1" style="display: none;">Ile d'Oléron (bekend schiereiland)</option>
<option value="10" s="s9" d="d13" style="display: none;">Ile de Noirmoutier (charmant schiereiland)</option>
<option value="28" s="s2" d="d1" style="display: none;">Ile de Ré (charmant eiland)</option>
<option value="31" s="s4" d="d7" style="display: none;">Invasiestranden (Manche)</option>
<option value="13" s="s4" d="d7" style="display: none;">Jersey en Guernsey (kanaaleilanden)</option>
<option value="33" s="s1" d="d5" style="display: none;">La pointe du Raz (indrukwekkende kaap)</option>
<option value="30" s="s2" d="d1" style="display: none;">La Rochelle (pittoreske havenstad)</option>
<option value="17" s="s6" d="d9" style="display: none;">Le Touquet (luxe badplaats)</option>
<option value="18" s="s9" d="d13" style="display: none;">Les Sables d'Olonne (bekende badplaats)</option>
<option value="29" s="s6" d="d15" style="display: none;">Lille (historische kunststad)</option>
<!-- BUG OR FAULT ENDS HERE -->
<option value="16" s="s1" d="d6" style="display: none;">Mont St. Michel (wereldbekende abdij)</option>
<option value="19" s="s9" d="d12" style="display: none;">Nantes (statige stad)</option>
<option value="20" s="s6" d="d9" style="display: none;">Opaalkust (kliffen en fijne zandstranden)</option>
<option value="21" s="s1" d="d2" style="display: none;">Perros Guirec (vogelreservaat)</option>
<option value="25" s="s1" d="d8" style="display: none;">Quiberon (prachtig schiereiland)</option>
<option value="32" s="s1" d="d5" style="display: none;">Roscoff (bekende badplaats)</option>
<option value="22" s="s4" d="d10" style="display: none;">Rouen (stad van Jeanne d'Arc)</option>
<option value="24" s="s6" d="d16" style="display: inline;">Saint Valéry sur Somme (middeleeuwse stad)</option>
<option value="23" s="s1" d="d6" style="display: inline;">St. Malo (zeeroversstad)</option>
<option value="26" s="s4" d="d4" style="display: none;">Tuinen van Monet (Giverny)</option>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome- display:none options in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177113/chrome-displaynone-options-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

this works in Firefox, but is a known bug in Chrome.

The suggested workaround is to wrap the option in a span to hide it. 
Check out this question for some example code:
[How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)