# Strange Dropdown options in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

My HTML for dropdown:

```
<select>
    <option style="display:block;">--Please Select --</option>
    <option style="display:block;">one</option>
    <option style="display:none;">two</option>
    <option style="display:none;">three</option>
</select>
```

Issue: It displays like one by one line scrolling in chrome. No issues in Firefox and other browsers.

Attached image for clear reference.

[image: Chrome dropdown]

Please help!

Comment: Do you have some style on the select, or is the parent limited in height? You can find out by right-click on the select and choose "inspect element"

Comment: Hi Luc, There is no style applied and there is no limitation in height as well for the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is changing the height of the drop down to render as the height of the first visible options to the specific size. If I put two at the top, I get two lines, three visible options gives three lines and so on. The other options are still there but only with the scrollbar.

Hiding options using display: none breaks in more browsers.

> I found instead of hiding the options, we don't need options from the
>   select itself rather using display: none.

Reference: [Chrome- display:none options in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177113/chrome-displaynone-options-in-select)