# Dropdown in html

Tags: html

I have a dropdown for US states in html. But when I go through the list, it goes expanding over the page. Is there any way i can limit this?
I don't want to display it using size=" " property.

Comment: You mean it expands downward too far, or too far to the right? Or both?

Comment: Upward. I have this problem with safari. When I ran the same code in Mozilla, its not having same issue.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is controlled by the browser and can't be changed.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown/570651#570651) for more information.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try styling it with **CSS**.

Here's an example:

```
.fakelist { height: 30px; }
```