# Select and Option tag i.e dropdown in html show complete list

Tags: html

I have 25-30 options in my `<select> </select>`
tag, when i click on the select from drop down list. I get the list of first 20 options only and after that i have to scroll down the the list to select onwards i.e. for 21 to further.

But my requirement is that when click on dropdown to select, the complete list should be shown that is all 25-30 options should be shown, no scroll bar.

Pleae help me.. I had done lot of googling on it, but not got any solution.

Answer (score 0):

try that snippet

```
$('select').on('click', function(){
    $('select').attr('size', $('select option').size());
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/gskad/)

Comment: That's not a dropdown dude

Comment: fails again http://jsfiddle.net/gskad/4/

Comment: Actually this is not possible..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:

[Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown/570651#570651)

As accepted answer states - there is no way to do that. Suppose you will need to use custom JS drop down to achieve that.

Comment: Then close the question as an exact duplicate, why not?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `size` ot the `select` element, specifies the number of visible options in a drop-down list.

If the value of the size attribute is greater than 1, but lower than the total number of options in the list, the browser will add a scroll bar to indicate that there are more options to view.

If you use `JQuery` you can find the number of options in your select list like this:

```
var count = $("#mySelect :selected").length;
```

and set the `size` attribute to this number, like this:

```
$("select").attr('size',count);
```