# How to adjust Select drop-down height

Tags: html, html-select

I've looking round the internet for a solution to this and everyone is talking about different things or just saying **does *size="x"* help**? I've made a Plunk to illustrate my issue. On my screen I can see up to item 20 when I click the drop down. I'd like to be able to set this to show more, or at least have some control.

http://plnkr.co/edit/gsFK5NmHKo4xopYBruD6?p=preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot because the select box is a system control..

See [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

You could use a dropdown replacement widget/module..

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of this point. I was just hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: the link is valid, but with invalid JS.

Comment: Can't the shadow DOM be used for system controls?

Answer (score -9):

You are add size tag like this

```
   <select size="30">
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. I've highlighted in my question that this isn't what I'm looking for. It needs to be drop down.