# jQuery select dropdown, goes too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am again with a new question. I have two select boxes, the first is for towns and the second are all the universities.  The problem is that when i choose a town with many universities (ex ΑΘΗΝΑ), I get correctly the drop-down of second select box. But if I click on a town with less universities (ΚΑΒΑΛΑ) I get only 2 rows displayed and the drop-down is too small. Can anyone help me please? here is the example on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdanaskos/7aTJ7/)

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.poli').change(function () {
    var str2 = $(".poli option:selected").text();
    $('#sxoli option').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass(str2) || $(this).hasClass("all")) {
        $(this).removeAttr('hidden');
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      } else {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).attr('hidden', 'hidden');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Πόλη Φοίτησης:
<br>
<select class="poli" id="poli" name="poli">
    <option value="">Επιλέξτε</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΓ. ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΣ ΚΡΗΤΗΣ">ΑΓ. ΝΙΚΟΛΑΟΣ ΚΡΗΤΗΣ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΓΡΙΝΙΟ">ΑΓΡΙΝΙΟ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΘΗΝΑ">ΑΘΗΝΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΙΓΙΟ">ΑΙΓΙΟ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΥΠΟΛΗ">ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΥΠΟΛΗ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΜΑΛΙΑΔΑ">ΑΜΑΛΙΑΔΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΜΦΙΣΣΑ">ΑΜΦΙΣΣΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΡΓΟΣΤΟΛΙ">ΑΡΓΟΣΤΟΛΙ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΑΡΤΑ">ΑΡΤΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΒΟΛΟΣ">ΒΟΛΟΣ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΓΡΕΒΕΝΑ">ΓΡΕΒΕΝΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΔΙΔΥΜΟΤΕΙΧΟ">ΔΙΔΥΜΟΤΕΙΧΟ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΔΡΑΜΑ">ΔΡΑΜΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΖΑΚΥΝΘΟΣ">ΖΑΚΥΝΘΟΣ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΗΓΟΥΜΕΝΙΤΣΑ">ΗΓΟΥΜΕΝΙΤΣΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟ">ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ">ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΘΗΒΑ">ΘΗΒΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΚΑΒΑΛΑ">ΚΑΒΑΛΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΚΑΛΑΜΑΤΑ">ΚΑΛΑΜΑΤΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΚΑΡΔΙΤΣΑ">ΚΑΡΔΙΤΣΑ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΚΑΡΠΕΝΗΣΙ">ΚΑΡΠΕΝΗΣΙ</option>
    <option id="poli_opt" value="ΚΑΣΤΟΡΙΑ">ΚΑΣΤΟΡΙΑ</option>
<br>Σχολή:
<br>
<select id="sxoli" name="sxoli">
    <option value="" class="all">Επιλέξτε</option>
    <option value="-" class="all" style="color:black;">--------------------------------------------------------Α.Ε.Ι--------------------------------------------------------</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ" value="ΑΓΓΛΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΑΓΓΛΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <br>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ" value="ΑΓΡΟΝ. & ΤΟΠΟΓ. ΜΗΧ.">ΑΓΡΟΝ. & ΤΟΠΟΓ. ΜΗΧ.</option>
    <option class="ΟΡΕΣΤΙΑΔΑ" value="ΑΓΡΟΤ. ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ">ΑΓΡΟΤ. ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΑΓΡΟΤ. ΟΙΚΟΝΟΜΙΑΣ & ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ">ΑΓΡΟΤ. ΟΙΚΟΝΟΜΙΑΣ & ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="Ανώτατη Σχολή Καλών Τεχνών">Ανώτατη Σχολή Καλών Τεχνών</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΑΞΙΟΠ. ΦΥΣ. ΠΟΡΩΝ & ΓΕΩΡΓ. ΜΗΧ/ΚΗΣ">ΑΞΙΟΠ. ΦΥΣ. ΠΟΡΩΝ & ΓΕΩΡΓ. ΜΗΧ/ΚΗΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΑΞΙΩΜ. ΝΟΣΗΛ. (ΣΑΝ)">ΑΞΙΩΜ. ΝΟΣΗΛ. (ΣΑΝ)</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΑΞΙΩΜΑΤΙΚΩΝ ΕΛΛ. ΑΣΤΥΝΟΜΙΑΣ">ΑΞΙΩΜΑΤΙΚΩΝ ΕΛΛ. ΑΣΤΥΝΟΜΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΚΕΡΚΥΡΑ" value="ΑΡΧΕΙΟΝΟΜΙΑΣ & ΒΙΒΛΙΟΘ/ΜΙΑΣ, ΜΟΥΣΕΙΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΑΡΧΕΙΟΝΟΜΙΑΣ & ΒΙΒΛΙΟΘ/ΜΙΑΣ, ΜΟΥΣΕΙΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΒΟΛΟΣ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ ΞΑΝΘΗ ΠΑΤΡΑ ΧΑΝΙΑ" value="ΑΡΧΙΤΕΚΤΟΝΩΝ ΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΩΝ">ΑΡΧΙΤΕΚΤΟΝΩΝ ΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΑΣΤΥΦΥΛΑΚΩΝ">ΑΣΤΥΦΥΛΑΚΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ" value="ΒΑΛΚΑΝΙΚΩΝ - ΣΛΑΒΙΚΩΝ & ΑΝΑΤ. ΣΠΟΥΔΩΝ">ΒΑΛΚΑΝΙΚΩΝ - ΣΛΑΒΙΚΩΝ & ΑΝΑΤ. ΣΠΟΥΔΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ ΠΑΤΡΑ" value="ΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΙΩΑΝΝΙΝΑ" value="ΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΚΩΝ ΕΦΑΡΜΟΓΩΝ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΩΝ">ΒΙΟΛΟΓΙΚΩΝ ΕΦΑΡΜΟΓΩΝ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΠΕΙΡΑΙΑΣ" value="ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΗΣ ΔΙΟΙΚΗΣΗΣ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΗΣ ΔΙΟΙΚΗΣΗΣ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΒΙΟΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΒΙΟΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΛΑΡΙΣΑ" value="ΒΙΟΧΗΜΕΙΑΣ & ΒΙΟΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΒΙΟΧΗΜΕΙΑΣ & ΒΙΟΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ" value="ΓΑΛΛΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΓΑΛΛΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ" value="ΓΕΡΜΑΝΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΓΕΡΜΑΝΙΚΗΣ ΓΛΩΣΣΑΣ & ΦΙΛΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ ΜΥΤΙΛΗΝΗ" value="ΓΕΩΓΡΑΦΙΑΣ">ΓΕΩΓΡΑΦΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΓΕΩΛΟΓΙΑΣ & ΓΕΩΠΕΡΙΒΑΛΛΟΝΤΟΣ">ΓΕΩΛΟΓΙΑΣ & ΓΕΩΠΕΡΙΒΑΛΛΟΝΤΟΣ</option>
    <option class="ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ ΠΑΤΡΑ" value="ΓΕΩΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΓΕΩΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option>
    <option class="ΒΟΛΟΣ" value="ΓΕΩΠΟΝΙΑΣ ΙΧΘΥΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ ΚΑΙ ΥΔΑΤΙΝΟΥ ΠΕΡΙΒΑΛΛΟΝΤΟΣ">ΓΕΩΠΟΝΙΑΣ ΙΧΘΥΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ ΚΑΙ ΥΔΑΤΙΝΟΥ ΠΕΡΙΒΑΛΛΟΝΤΟΣ</option>
    <option class="ΒΟΛΟΣ" value="ΓΕΩΠΟΝΙΑΣ, ΦΥΤΙΚ. ΠΑΡΑΓΩΓΗΣ ΚΑΙ ΑΓΡΟΤΙΚΟΥ ΠΕΡΙΒΑΛ.">ΓΕΩΠΟΝΙΑΣ, ΦΥΤΙΚ. ΠΑΡΑΓΩΓΗΣ ΚΑΙ ΑΓΡΟΤΙΚΟΥ ΠΕΡΙΒΑΛ.</option> 
    <option class="ΘΗΒΑ" value="ΔΙΟΙΚΗΣΗΣ ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΕΦΟΔΙΑΣΜΟΥ">ΔΙΟΙΚΗΣΗΣ ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΕΦΟΔΙΑΣΜΟΥ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΔΙΟΙΚΗΤΙΚΗΣ ΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΗΣ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓ. ΟΙΚ/ΚΟΥ">ΔΙΟΙΚΗΤΙΚΗΣ ΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΗΣ & ΤΕΧΝΟΛΟΓ. ΟΙΚ/ΚΟΥ</option>
    <option class="ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ ΦΛΩΡΙΝΑ" value="ΕΙΚΑΣΤΙΚΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΕΦΑΡΜΟΣΜΕΝΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ">ΕΙΚΑΣΤΙΚΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΕΦΑΡΜΟΣΜΕΝΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΕΙΚΑΣΤΙΚΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ">ΕΙΚΑΣΤΙΚΩΝ ΤΕΧΝΩΝ</option>
    <option class="ΑΘΗΝΑ" value="ΕΚΠ/ΚΩΝ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ">ΕΚΠ/ΚΩΝ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΛΟΓΙΑΣ</option> 
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a system control, not a browser one [1].  Your best bet is to use a dropdown replacement plugin [like Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/a/16788975/1216976

Comment: Bootstrap has a nice, well-supported plugin: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for plugins in this case then Try harvest chosen plugin.