# Vertical scroll in Select html

Tags: html, css

Can you have a vertical scroll in select html,,,

But keeping size="1" So when you click on the drop list it displays only around 5 options and the rest are viewed when you scroll.

I have a [fiddel here](http://jsfiddle.net/benandersen/VxNV9/)

```
form name="#">

 <div class="select-style2"> 

     <select  size="1" autocomplete="off">

<option hidden value="#">title</option>
<option value="#">2</option>
<option value="#">3 </option>
<option value="#">4 </option>
<option value="#">5 </option>
<option value="#">6 </option>
<option value="#">7 </option>
<option value="#">8 </option>
<option value="#">9 </option>
<option value="#">10 </option>




</select>
</div>
<input type="button" name="test" value="Go"
onClick="go()" id="btn">
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense though, why would you do that

Comment: Sure it make sense, if you have a giant list

Comment: I'd love an example where that'd happen, but I can understand :)

Comment: I have my reasons, one being design !!, and two the list is around 20.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous answer points out, there isn't good styling options for `select` dropdowns.

However, the good news is, the answer to your question "Can you have a vertical scroll in select html" is yes. It's there by default when you have enough options in the list. But changing that number seems impossible with css.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VxNV9/1/

But you could create a custom drop down in jquery/javascript and style it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do in HTML. In SO, they have already discussed about this. [**Check It out Here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

May be there are other ways of achiving this through javascript or jQuery, with links on that page to some jQuery plugins which create a "fake" html select box that looks and behaves like one, but can have the height set.