# How to prevent <select> height from shrinking after filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/z56Vq/)

### HTML

```
<select>
    <option class="a">aaaaa</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="a">a</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
    <option class="b">b</option>
</select>
<button>click me</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('button').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('.a').prop('disabled',true);
    if($('select').find('option:selected').prop('disabled')) {
        $('select').find('option:enabled:first').prop('selected',true);
    };
});
```

### CSS

```
option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

Open the fiddle in Chrome. Click the `<select>`. Observe its height. Click the button. Open the `<select>` again. Notice how much shorter it is, despite there still being plenty of values in there.

Why is Chrome excessively shortening the dropdown list? I want it to be whatever its natural height is, which should be about the same as what it was the first time you opened it. Can I force Chrome to recompute its natural height?

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/54rhz/) should be more clear. Pop open each of the selects. Notice they're different heights, despite displaying the same values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  Do you want to see every option in the select list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown

Comment: @Stanley_A No, just whatever it would be if I didn't filter it. This should make it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/54rhz/ look at the heights of the two different dropdowns when you open them. They have different heights despite displaying the exact same values. I want them to be the same.

Comment: @Banana I don't want to explicitly set the height of the dropdown. I just want it to not be dumb.

Comment: @Mark apparently thats the way it is, and theres nothing you can do about it... :/

Comment: @Banana Works fine in Firefox. I think its a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason behind it (changing list while being opened), maybe there isn't, I wouldn't know. I'd look into simply removing the items, rather than adding a class to hide them. Is there any specific reason why that'd be undesired?

Comment: @Aidiakapi Yes, because I'm redisplaying them later. This is the best way I've found to maintain the order of the options and all their properties without doing some major insert/remove hackery.

Comment: i think i know why it happens. try removing the `display:hidden` from the disabled items css and count the height of the drop down. as soon as the items are being disabled, their total height is being subtracted from the initially calculated dropdown height. im trying to figure out how to bypass this though...

Comment: here is the issue on that: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139595

Comment: this was reported 2 years ago, if it was not fixed yet then maybe its not a bug?

Comment: you can bypass the issue if you simply remove the items instead of disabling them... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/54rhz/1/)

Comment: Here is another playground with things to think about: http://jsfiddle.net/z56Vq/2/

Comment: @Banana If I remove them, how do I re-add them, maintaining order? I'm using this for a filter. Also, how can it *not* be a bug? This in no way makes sense, and none of the other browsers have this issue.

Comment: @Banana I think your count theory may be correct. Here is another disturbing demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z56Vq/3/ Readonly has the same effect as disabled items. But it's funny to see that the `<select multiple="multiple" />` is showing options that should be `display: none;` even the developer tool shows that.. strange. Update: Check this in Firefox. When you open the second select under "readonly" (not multiple) and select one, it will suddenly hide the first elements that should be hidden right away.

Comment: how about keeping the whole list in JavaScript array, and populating the selects when needed? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/54rhz/2/)

Comment: well it might be a bug, but google chrome was at its 20nd version at the time that was reported.  its 35  now, if in 15 releases this thing was not fixed, i think its safe to assume that it is not a bug...

Comment: @Banana I think that just means they're unwilling to fix it because only 7 people care about it. Based on your "array" suggestion [I came up with this](https://gist.github.com/mnbayazit/efb99e87718607b39917). We don't need to use an array and recreate elements, but we do need to maintain a reference to the options outside of the DOM. This should maintain any attributes, classes and whatever else was added to the option.

Answer (score 3):

[It's a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139595) (thanks [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3244925/nico-o) for finding this) and there's [no workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown) (thanks [Banana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406576/banana)).

If you want the height to be computed correctly, you have to actually remove the `<options>` from the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

You can give `onchange` so that the code which will work.

Here is your Answer [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ESWe/24/)

**CODE**:

```
 <select onchange="(this.value)">
</select>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where have you defined the `showdropdown` function?

Comment: @Mark: what is wrong in my answer, that showdropdown function was given by myself.

Comment: i downvoted your answer, because your fiddle does not solve Mark's issue

Comment: @Banana: he asks the dropdown should have a corresponding height, here now its working fine, then why did you down vote for my answer.

Comment: @KesaVan because it does not, in chrome it still changes height in your fiddle.

Comment: @Banana: see friend,In my system it works fine in chrome browser, so only i posted the answer,without knowing why doing down vote,

Comment: @KesaVan you chose mootools framework instead of jquery, thats why it appears to you like its working, but in fact the whole code does not execute thats why the drop down height remains intact...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57110/discussion-between-kesavan-and-banana).