# Angularjs drop down at the bottom of the page is not displaying items, unable to control number of items shown

Tags: angularjs

I tried setting size to 2 or 1, it did not make any difference.

I also read [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Is there no other option apart from using the plugin - http://programmingdrunk.com/current-projects/dropdownReplacement/?

**Code from Comment:**

```
 <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="color" chosen ng-model="obj.color" ng-options=" color.name for color in colors" size=1>  
   <option value=""></option>
```

Comment: I never used the plugin and can't help you without seeing some of your code, but why not use angular's native dropdown: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Here is the code, since the drop down is at the bottom of the page, I cannot view all the items - <select class="form-control" data-placeholder="color" chosen ng-model="obj.color" ng-options=" color.name for color in colors" size=1>
                            <option value=""></option>

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand your problem, you are using a native angular dropdown, it's positioned at the bottom of your page and the dropdown is opening downwards and you can't see all of the options. It would really help if you had a screnshot of the result, how it would look when it's working and the code.                    Anyway, the probable cause is an `overflow:hidden` style on one of your parent elements.

Comment: Thanks! It now works with overflow-y: scroll; and max-height: 40px;

Comment: No problem, do you want to answer your own question or would you like me to post a more generic explanation which may be more helpful for future viewers?

Comment: I have a problem now. Since the max-height is very small, when a  drop-down is near the top of the page, it is looking very odd. Need to have more max-height for those drop-downs. How do I achieve that - different max-height for different drop-downs?