# How set height of select dropdown list in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, html-select

I found a bug with select tag in IE 9... In IE 10 and 11, FF, Chrome, Safari everything works fine, but in IE 9 - when list with options become visible, it's going over , browser window and monitor display:

[image]

May I somehow manually set height of options list, or set count of visible options (before scrolling) using CSS and JS?

P.S. it's just select tag and many options inside.

Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot because the select box is a system control.

Example [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)