# Height of selectbox in dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/5huhxj65/4/) which is controlled by another dropdown as,

```
$("#change").change(function() {
    if(this.value == "x") {
        $("#mydp").parent().show();
       $( "#mydp option[value='r']" ).nextAll().andSelf().css("display", "none");
         $( "#mydp option[value='r']" ).prevUntil( "#mydp option[value='']" ).css("display", "initial");
    } else if(this.value == "y") {
          $("#mydp").parent().show();
      $( "#mydp option[value='r']" ).nextAll().andSelf().css("display", "initial");
         $( "#mydp option[value='r']" ).prevUntil( "#mydp option[value='']" ).css("display", "none");

    } else {
         $("#mydp").parent().hide();
    }
});
```

If I select `y` in first dropdown, why the height of second dropdown's selectbox become reduced and how can i set auto height for it?

Answer (score 0):

Your select gets screwed because `.css("display", "initial")` actually sets `display: inline` for every `<option>` instead of the default `display: block`.

For details check this: [Reset CSS display property to default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value)

The proper way to hide/unhide an element in jQuery is via `.show()`/`.hide()`:

```
$("#change").change(function() {
    if(this.value == "x") {
        $("#mydp").parent().show();
        $r = $( "#mydp option[value='r']" );

        $r.nextAll().andSelf().hide();
        $r.prevUntil( "#mydp option[value='']" ).show();
    } 
    else if(this.value == "y") {
        $("#mydp").parent().show();
        $r = $( "#mydp option[value='r']" );

        $r.nextAll().andSelf().show();
        $r.prevUntil( "#mydp option[value='']" ).hide();
    } 
    else {
         $("#mydp").parent().hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `.show()/.hide()` also tried. But not working: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/5huhxj65/5/

Comment: Seems to work fine. What do you want the second dropdown to display?

Comment: But I want to avoid the scrollbar in second dropdown when selecting `y` in first. See the fiddle in above comment.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you can not set custom height for the dropdown box of a select. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown Instead you might wanna use one of the jQuery dropdown plugins instead. E.g. http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: when x is selected in first drop down, and then select second, all the options are populating. But if I select y in first and then select second, a scrollbar appears. I want to remove that scrollbar.