# How to change the size of a "select box" form

Tags: css, html, symfony, twig

A client doesn't want to scroll in a select form so I need to increase the size of my select form.

I tried this but still doesn't work, I only see 4 inputs :

```
{{ form_widget(filterForm.accomodationFilter1, { attr: { class: 'fancyselect filter type' }, {'size': '10'} }) }}
```

Any idea how I can do that and where is the documentation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it directly in the formBuilder:

```
->add('example', 'choice', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'fancyselect filter type',
                             'style' => 'max-width:100px'),
            'choices' => 'choices',
            )
```

Or just use:

```
->add('example', 'choice', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'fancyselect filter type'),
            'choices' => 'choices',
            'max_length' => 100,
            )
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but still, doesn't work ... I have no notable effect of this. Got an idea why ?

Comment: I just saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown , and it seems like it is impossible to do ?!

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question I thought you were trying to customise the "select" and yes tell your client that it's impossible to do.

Comment: You could take a look at some jquery select box replacements